# BigQuery API jobs oauth and Google account change

Tags: google-bigquery, google-oauth, google-cloud-iam

I have a problem with BigQuery and I wonder if any of you already had to struggle with something similar.

A gmail address was accidentally associated with the Google account based on a corporative email address becoming the one that appears as the admin of all of the Google tools we are using: Google Analytics, Adwords, etc.

We solved it adding the corporative address again as admin and removing permissions to the gmail address.

The last tool to "fix" is BigQuery. We have a lot of jobs that extract data via API. The oauth process and the historical jobs shows at this moment the gmail login, not the previous one.

If we remove the secondary (gmail) account, will the jobs work taking automatically the original address as the login user for the Oauth process? Or will we have to modify all the scripts? Will the job history be lost?

Regards.

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly you mean by "modifying all scripts".  Ideally, you should have no account information in your scripts.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Michael, and thanks for your answer. You are right. We just had to get a new token.